# JPQL query SELECT optional + generic DAO select

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, jpql

I have followed a working JPA example to retrieve Category objects as such:

```
return (ArrayList<Category>) getEntityManager().createQuery("from Category").getResultList();
```

The query is very shorthand - and I can't find the rules for what is optional and what isn't in any of the guides. Is this brevity acceptable?

Secondly, I want to now implement this in a generic DAO, something such as:

```
public interface DAO<E, K>
{
    List<E> getAll();
}
```

How can I rewrite the first query to work for all types as I can't hardcode the "from Category"..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes, the brevity is acceptable. Although I prefer the full syntax because it is more "appealing" to others who have more SQL experience.
2. You have to add a `Class<E>` parameter to your DAO:

   ```
   public List<E> getAll(Class<E> entityClass) {
        Query query = enittyManager.createQuery("from " + entityClass.getName());
        query.getResultList();
   }
   ```

Comment: thanks for the tip, I am getting the classname in the generic dao's constructor and using that variable in the query!

Comment: @Mobs fine :) btw, accepted answers with 0 upvotes look weird ;)

Answer (score 2):

You actually don't have to use a method parameter, but can use Reflection.

[Example Code using Reflection](http://code.google.com/p/listwidget/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/com/turbomanage/listwidget/server/service/ObjectifyDao.java)

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public class<T> DAO {         
    protected Class<T> clazz;

    public DAO()
    {
      Type genericSuperclass = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
      // Allow this class to be safely instantiated with or without a parameterized type
      if (genericSuperclass instanceof ParameterizedType)
        clazz = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) genericSuperclass).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }
}
```